# Android Studio ignores some breakpoints, while others work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, xml-parsing

in Android Studio I would like to analyze my variables with breakpoints, but some of them are just ignored, while others work. I have no idea why.
I am especially interested in the variables of the following method. 
Do have any idea why the debugger ignores the breakpoints in it?

```
private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "searchresults");
    String longitude = null;
    String latitude = null;
    String place_id = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("place")) {
            longitude = readLongitude(parser);
            latitude = readLatitude(parser);
            place_id = readPlace_id(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return new Entry(longitude, latitude, place_id);
}
```

As you might have guessed I am trying to parse an XML document in an Async Task and this is one step of the way. I am trying to find out, what I did wrong while parsing this xml document:

```
<searchresults timestamp="Fri, 26 Aug 16 10:38:53 +0000" attribution="Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" querystring="warmbandwerk" polygon="false" exclude_place_ids="129799074,151481629" more_url="http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=xml&exclude_place_ids=129799074,151481629&accept-language=de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3&q=warmbandwerk">
<place place_id="129799074" osm_type="way" osm_id="220625788" place_rank="30" boundingbox="51.4947849,51.497683,6.7382846,6.746241" lat="51.49646145" lon="6.74226302912559" display_name="Warmbandwerk 1, Kaiser-Wilhelm-Straße, ThyssenKrupp Steel Europe AG, Hamborn, Duisburg, Regierungsbezirk Düsseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 47166, Deutschland" class="building" type="yes" importance="0.101"/>
<place place_id="151481629" osm_type="relation" osm_id="2917388" place_rank="30" boundingbox="51.4860521,51.4891516,6.7050164,6.7144352" lat="51.48741265" lon="6.70882226405504" display_name="Warmbandwerk 2, Werkstraße 1, ThyssenKrupp Steel Europe AG, Beeckerwerth, Meiderich/Beeck, Duisburg, Regierungsbezirk Düsseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 47139, Deutschland" class="building" type="yes" importance="0.101"/>
</searchresults>
```

edit: Because someone asked which breakpoints do not work. In the above method none of them work. In the method below all of them work until the for-statement. The for-statement and return breakpoints are ignored.

```
    private String loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    // Instantiate the parser
    XMLParser XMLParser = new XMLParser();
    List<XMLParser.Entry> entries = null;

    StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder();
    htmlString.append("<h3>" + getResources().getString(R.string.page_title) + "</h3>");
    htmlString.append("<em>" + getResources().getString(R.string.updated));

    try {
        stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        entries = XMLParser.parse(stream);
        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    // StackOverflowXmlParser returns a List (called "entries") of Entry objects.
    // Each Entry object represents a single post in the XML feed.
    // This section processes the entries list to combine each entry with HTML markup.
    // Each entry is displayed in the UI as a link that optionally includes
    // a text summary.
    for (XMLParser.Entry entry : entries) {
        htmlString.append("<p><a href='");
        htmlString.append(entry.longitude);
        htmlString.append(entry.latitude);
        htmlString.append(entry.place_id);
    }

    return htmlString.toString();
}
```

Comment: Which breakpoints are "not working"? Why not just put a breakpoint where it works then Step Into the next lines of code until you get to where you want? Normally when a breakpoint is not hit its because the code flow does not enter that logical element.

Comment: @Kon I edited my question because of what you asked.

Comment: I suspect an exception is causing it to escape the entire block? Can you check if an exception is being thrown in the cases you mention? Right before the for loop

Comment: Some lines of code cannot be reached because of conditions in loops and if-statements. You can put breakpoint at first line inside the method and then move on line by line by pressing `F8`.